# KitKat 'onLoad()' runtime exception

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an app that uses `onLoad()` to load a native library (SQL Cipher). When I ran this on my Nexus 5 it fails with a runtime exception.

After doing some research I have come across [an app with the same problem](https://getsatisfaction.com/dashlane/topics/dashlane_crashes_on_nexus_5_running_kitkat). Their explanation is: "the issue showed up because google closed a part of the NDK api as private, so basically when we try to initialize the native code it fails on onLoad() " -

Has anyone come across this and fixed it? I'm guessing this will be a common problem as KitKat becomes more popular.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a [new version](http://sqlcipher.net/blog/2013/6/27/sqlcipher-220-release.html) of SQLCipher? They've removed usage of that private class.

Comment: Thanks, yes. That fixed it. Was just coming back here to update lol

Comment: It seems like usage of onLoad() is not itself the problem - the actual deprecated private API is buried further inside.

Comment: I had the same issue.  Upgrading the SQLCipher 2.2 fixed the problem.  See: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/107